# retrieve emails addresses from the searchResultSet and send an email

Tags: java

I have these 2 methods in different 2 java classes.
The target of this is to retrieve the searchResultSet and take first email and send an email then the second email and send same email.

Now the resultSet gives me the emails that I want them to receive this email but it did not send any email like it did not retrieve the first email and second because I have to save these emails as string then pass them in the toEmail variable.

first class:

```
public List<UserDto> getEmail() {
    
    Connection connection = null;
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
    
    try {
    
        connection = getConnection();
    
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')");
                
        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    
        return getEmail(searchResultSet);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


private List<UserDto> getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<UserDto> result = new ArrayList<UserDto >();

    UserDto userDto = null;
  
    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        userDto = new UserDto();

        userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));
        result.add(userDto);
       
     }
     return result;
}
```

after this I have 2 emails.
now I have to take first one and send email using this in second class then the second email:

```
Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

List<UserDto> users = delegate.getEmail();
String toEmail = users.toString();

delegate.sendNotification("****", "****", toEmail , "", "",
                   "", body);
```

Any ideas!!!!!

Comment: So you have to send two emails to every user, what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: one email for all. The problem that I face now that I can not get or retrieve these 2 emails in second class from the first methods or from the searchResultSet to put them in toEmiail variable and send an email, also I do not have any error.